# Isolated Development Environment

Tags: gtk, development-environment, virtualbox, fedora

I'd like to ask for recommendations for a development environment with the following basic requirements:

- on recent Fedora (e.g. 13 or 14) GNU/linux distribution
- developing gtk+ apps with C
- isolated (installation of files shouldn't affect the main system's system files)
- allows for cheap snapshot of the entire development files

So far, the only two options I can think of are chroot jail and virtualized guest. I had a very hard time to get chroot jail to work properly with dbus (ended up snapshotting my entire system using btrfs). Also used recent VirtualBox which feels extra sluggish recently.

I would really like to know what the devs here use as their development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use two virtualized OpenBSD (CLI only) and Debian (w/ GUI) environments with backups, so I just wipe them clean when I need too. I use VirtualBox or VMWare.